# What is the step by step procedure that leads the T cell to release chemokines?

Tags: human-biology, molecular-biology, cell-biology, cell-signaling, pathogenesis

When T cell receptors bind to the receptor of an antigen presenting cell, is this what leads to the release of chemokines? I know that T cell release of chemokines leads to the migration of other T cells to the area of infection. What is the step by step procedure that leads to this release of chemokines from a T cell?